# Animating a for loop in javascript (canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I made a for loop which draws 40 rectangles , they all need have height: 400px; but I want to start at height: 0; and animate to 400 with `requestAnimationFrame` This is my code :

```
function draw(){

    height += 5;
        if(height > 1){
            for (var i = 0; i < dataSales.length; i++) {

                    geel += 6;
                    blauw += 6;
                    groen -= 6;
                    xPos += 23;
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle= "#89C349";
                    ctx.rect(xPos,595,20,-height);
                    ctx.fill();
            }
        }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
```

Comment: whats the issue? what part is/isnt working? what do you need help on?

Comment: if i do log i can see my height is going up, but my rectangles just draw at 5px height and stop.

Comment: can you show the full code? or better yet recreate in a jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dun1ezrx/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the second time `draw` gets called, `xPos = 907`, the third time `draw` gets called `xPos = 1804`, etc.

You want `xPos`, `geel`, `blauw` and `groen` to all be defined *inside* `draw` so that they reset every time. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a0b4mu2y/).

Comment: Thanks alot! , Now i still have a little problem , actually the bars should go as high according to the dataSales[] , like height = dataSales[i] / 800 , is there a way to do that?